# We forget to put one of the A card in our packet

Tags: hand-history

We've gotten a silly but important question for you.
Yesterday we played poker and after one of us won and took All the pot, we discover that one of the A cards was out out of the card's packet, and wasn't in play at all (during all of our hands).
This discovery started a massive debate immediately. On the one hand, some of as argue that the game was corrupted and that the result is not legite. On the other hand, the winner argued that all of us had a fair chance to win since no one knew about the A disappearance.

What do you say? Who is right? Is the result legite?

Answer (score 2):

The general rule is that if a deck is foul, IE not complete or with extra card(s) (or not relevant to you: found to be marked or in some other way compromised) the hand is considered void and the players will receive their bets back. It is important to note this needs to be found out before the next hand begins. The next hand begins when the dealer starts the shuffle, IE the first riffle to be precise is the beginning of the next hand.

Good thing to know going forward in your next game.

I would suggest you just let that last hand stand as it is. Although since this seems to be a home game you of course can remedy it if you like. If it was a casino game you cannot expect that this will be remedied, although they may own their mistake and comp you a buffet or even make it right for sometime after discovery, although they are under no obligation to make the money right after the hand is over, (that's why they have the rule, nothing nefarious they just need a point of no return).

Answer (score 0):

One would have to review the hand histories to see if anybody was actually affected by the card not being in play.

If affected then the hand has to be discarded.

If there are no reliable records then i would suggest that winner keeps a portion out of respect for time spent and a portion is returned to the players who might have been affected.

Disagreement about the cut can be arbitrated on agreed upon basis and money should be placed in safekeeping until resolved.

It being only 1 card, the loss to winner should be minimal and weighted against greater corruption. It's not like u were playing with half the deck is what i mean. There was certainly a lot of poker going down.

If you are going to play these people more then don't be shortsighted:)

If i dob't know the hands If i won a lot of money and future ev is low then i would hestitantly give up claim to more than 5-10% without communal or representative arbitration.

Answer (score 0):

Any player playing a hand where an A was an out, got massively worst odds than they should have (and played for).

If the missing card was a 3, maybe it's okay. But since poker (at least holdem) is high-card centric, the absence of an A is detrimental.

For instance, A player looking to pair an Ace preflop should have about 4.5:1 odds of hitting another A by the river. However, with an ace missing they actually got something closer to 7:1 against.

This messes up all expected value calculations.

I'd feel bad keeping the money.